# Why am I getting different actual image sizes using em and rem units in CSS

Tags: css

I'm struggling with the basics of rem CSS units. I understand that they are supposed to be relative to the root font size on the page. (The body, I presume.) I've set my body font-size to 18px, and was previously using a font-size of 0.75em for a particular class, which resulted in an actual size of 13.5px, as expected.

When I change that same element to have a size of 0.75rem, the actual size changes to 12px. Why?

Here's a very simple example:

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.firstChildDiv {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.secondChildDiv {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="firstChildDiv">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="secondChildDiv">
    Some more text
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's a screenshot from the Chrome developer tools:

[image]

Clearly, 0.75rem is leading to 12px, which means it must be calculating 0.75 * 16px. But I don't see where it's getting 16px from. The body clearly has a font-size of 18px.

Comment: em takes its size from the nearest parent so as in your body tag its 0.75em i.e. 18*0.75 = 13.5. But rem takes size from root element i.e. html tag and standard size is 16px so clearly 16*0.75 will give 12px.

Comment: `body` is *not* the root element that rem references. Change your css to apply font-size to `html` and your example will behave as expected.

Comment: Oooh, so you're saying that there's a different font-size on the html element? That makes sense, except I just don't see that in the Chrome developer tools. Is it better practice for me to set an explicit HTML font size so that I get consistent results?

Comment: Click on `show all` under `computed` in Chrome developer tools (or `browser styes` in Firefox). There you will see font-size on the HTML element which was set by the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: @ksav I did that, but it doesn't display the inheritance chain coming from the html element. It only goes as far back as body: https://www.evernote.com/l/ATOTnro2AMdH7pD63torIrpNjuMy9KYMuTMB/image.png